# Why does one of my new post lights not work?

Tags: lighting

I installed two post lights. The one on left works, the one on right does not. There is power to the light but still doesn't work. Changed bulbs and still doesn't work. I moved it to the left side and it works. What might the problem be on right side?

Comment: How did you verify that there's power to the light?

Comment: maybe the one that lights is actually faulty

Answer (score 2):

Most often if there is power and the bulbs work in another socket, the centre post of the socket is too low to touch the light bulb.

With the breaker off, carefully pull up the centre post a tiny bit(1/16 to 1/8 inch is plenty most times). Make sure the right breaker is off and no power at the socket.  Your finger/s might be in there, and you do not want to find there is still power there with your finger.

Possible a new socket is just defective, a wire not connected and should be returned, even if the repair is easy.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you correctly, you moved the entire post light from the right (where it didn't work) to the left (where it worked?)

If so, as I'd expect anyway, the method (you haven't said what) used to verify that there is power on the right side is suspect. *i.e.* a non-contact tester will tell you you have "power" if you have a hot wire and a disconnected neutral wire. That "power" won't *work* without a neutral to send current back to the source as a complete circuit.